# Replace ordered if condition with design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I've a legacy class with lots of if conditions, like:

```
public MyType methodWithIfs() {
  if (condition1) {
    return new MyType(param1);
  }

  if (condition2) {
    return new MyType(param2);
  }
  ....
}
```

Every if condition returns a type of `MyType`.

Also there is a order in which these conditions are mentioned. Two conditions can be true but only first that matched the criteria should be executed based on order.

I was thinking of replacing these conditions with [Conditional Dispatcher with Command](https://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/conditionDispatcherWithCommand.html) design pattern

Since there is an order to be maintained, instead of using `HashMap<Boolean, MyType>`, I was thinking of using `LinkedHashMap<Boolean, MyType>`.

But this seems dodgy. Is there any cleaner way I can replace these conditions?

*Thanks!*

Comment: Sounds more like a need for the `Factory` or even `Builder` pattern. There would need to be more information regarding the actual code in use.

Comment: I do agree with @Rogue. More information about the actual use case would be nice. Generally lots of if-statements or a switch statement are a good indicator that probably you could introduce an abstraction and make use of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

It's a perfect case for the factory pattern. From https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm:

> In Factory pattern, we create object without exposing the creation logic to the client and refer to newly created object using a common interface.

Since in all cases we are returning MyType instance, there is no problem to use that `methodWithIfs` body as a factory method, which would return MyType instance created in line with rules which we should keep in specific cases.

```
public MyType createMyType(Object param1, Object param2) {
  if (condition1) {
    return new MyType(param1);
  }

  if (condition2) {
    return new MyType(param2);
  }
  ....
}

public MyType methodWithIfs(){
    return createMyTypeObj(param1, param2)
}
```

It's kinda important when we are talking about design patterns - things like 100-line long switch/case or ifs chain aren't simply *internally* bad. It's all about **maintenance** - creating code in line with rules that would provide that the code will be clean, readable and easy to maintain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to use [Chain of Responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). As wiki says:

> The chain-of-responsibility pattern is a behavioral design pattern
> consisting of a source of command objects and a series of processing
> objects. **Each processing object contains logic that defines the
> types of command objects that it can handle; the rest are passed to
> the next processing object in the chain.** A mechanism also exists for
> adding new processing objects to the end of this chain

So let's dive in code. I am sorry, I am not Java guy. Let me show an example via C#. I've provided comments how code would be look in Java.

So this is out model class which we want to create based on some conditions:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string _color;

    public int _doorsCount;

    public int _wheelCount;

    public Vehicle(string color)
    {
        _color = color;
    }

    public Vehicle(int doorsCount)
    {
        _doorsCount = doorsCount;
    }

    public Vehicle(int doorsCount, int wheelCount)
    {
        _doorsCount = doorsCount;
        _wheelCount = wheelCount;
    }
}
```

And this is parameter class which you use in your `if else` statements:

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Parameter_1 { get; set; } // just simple variable in Java
    public string Parameter_2 { get; set; }
    public string Parameter_3 { get; set; }
}
```

And this is an abstraction of VehicleHandler which defines behaviour to to set next handler:

```
public abstract class VehicleHandler
{
    private VehicleHandler _nextVehicleHandler;

    public void SetSuccessor(VehicleHandler nextVehicleHandler)
    { 
        _nextVehicleHandler = nextVehicleHandler;
    }

    public virtual Vehicle Execute(Parameter parameter)
    { 
        if (_nextVehicleHandler != null)
            return _nextVehicleHandler.Execute(parameter);

        return null;
    }
}
```

and its concrete implementations of `VehicleHandler`:

```
public class FirstVehicleHandler : VehicleHandler // "inherits" in Java
{
    public override Vehicle Execute(Parameter parameter)
    {
        if (parameter.Parameter_1 != null)
            return new Vehicle("green");

        return base.Execute(parameter);
    }
}

public class SecondVehicleHandler : VehicleHandler // "inherits" in Java
{
    public override Vehicle Execute(Parameter parameter)
    {
        if (parameter.Parameter_2 != null)
            return new Vehicle(4);

        return base.Execute(parameter);
    }
}

public class ThirdVehicleHandler : VehicleHandler // "inherits" in Java
{
    public override Vehicle Execute(Parameter parameter)
    {
        if (parameter.Parameter_3 != null)
            return new Vehicle(4, 4);

        return base.Execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

And then you can call the above code like this:

```
VehicleHandler chain = new FirstVehicleHandler();
VehicleHandler secondVehicleHandler = new SecondVehicleHandler();
VehicleHandler thirdVehicleHandler = new ThirdVehicleHandler();

chain.SetSuccessor(secondVehicleHandler);
secondVehicleHandler.SetSuccessor(thirdVehicleHandler);

Parameter parameter = new Parameter();
parameter.Parameter_1 = "The color should be green";

Vehicle vehicle = chain.Execute(parameter); // color of vehicle is green
```